# Proof that for every $\lambda \in R$,$\exists \xi \in (0,\eta)$ s.t. $f'(\xi) - \lambda(f(\xi)-\xi)=1$

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$.$f(0)=f(1)=0,f(\frac 12)=1$. $\exists \eta \in (\frac 12, 1)$,s.t.$f(\eta)=\eta$.

Proof that for every $\lambda \in R$,$\exists \xi \in (0,\eta)$ s.t. $f'(\xi) - \lambda(f(\xi)-\xi)=1$.

I tried to use Darboux theorem. I noticed that $f'(x) - \lambda(f(x)-x)=1$ can be rewritten as $$\frac {g'(x)}{g(x)}= \lambda$$
where $g(x) = f(x) - x$.

And we also have

$$(ln(g(x)))'=\frac {g'(x)}{g(x)}$$

However, I have no idea about the next step. The approach I adopted might be wrong. Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may apply Rolle's theorem to the function $x\mapsto e^{-\lambda x} g(x)$: $g'(\xi) - \lambda g(\xi) = 0$ for a $\xi \in (0,\eta)$.